# How to add UIViewController as subview , to be visible above tabbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, addsubview

I want to add the view of a UIViewController as a subview. But self.view is having a UITabBarController. I want to display the subview above tabbar. So that tab bar hides behind subview.
Please suggest some idea.

Comment: you just hide the tabBar ! then display it again if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if you want to hide/show the UITabBarController of view:

For hide the tabbar:

```
 - (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
 {
     for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
     {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
       {
           [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, (isiPhone5?568:480), view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
           [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, isiPhone5?568: 480)];
        }
     }
  }
```

for show Tabbar:

```
   - (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
     {

         for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
         {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
               [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,  (isiPhone5?519:431), view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
               [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width,  isiPhone5?519:431)];
            }
         }
      }
```

may be it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Where you alloc and initialize TabBar, write this line

```
objectOfTabbar.hidden=YES;
```

Then give the frame of your subview same as of `TabBarController`.
This way your tabbar will be hidden and view will be shown .