# In IOS how to add UITabBarController in specific UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I want to add a tab bar in my project.Suppose i have total six view controller. Now i am trying to add tab bar only the third number of view controller. How can i do this? I have tried to do this.I have add codes in app delegate.m but after writing the code in app delegate the effects are coming into all view controllers.

Comment: for that you have to hide and show your tabbar in whatever your controller as per you want.

Comment: please add code examples.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999532/how-to-add-uiviewcontroller-as-subview-to-be-visible-above-tabbar/20000657#20000657

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your custom UITabBarController

```
-(void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
if( UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)){
    fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
}
if(!hidden) fHeight -= self.tabBar.frame.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]){
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }else{
            if(hidden) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
            }
        }
    }
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if(!hidden){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
            {
                if(![view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
                    if (!hidden) {
                        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
                        for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
                            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]){
                                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
                            }else{
                                if(hidden) {
                                    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}];}
```

In this delegate method of UITabBarController

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
```

You can do a check wether to show or hide the TabBar according to which viewController it is